# Linear Transformations question

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I understand A I believe. My questions are for b-d. I don't really understand how to start/what is being asked. Is b just asking if some polynomial is linear? Any tips/hints would be awesome.

Comment: Write $p(t) = \sum_k a_k t^k$. What can  you say?

Answer (score 1):

I believe we should think of the polynomial as a sum $p(t) = c_nt^n + c_{n-1}t^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1t + c_0$, and define $T^k$ as the composition $\underbrace{T\circ T \circ \ldots \circ T}_{k \text{ times }}$ which is a function $T^k: V \to V$.

Thus, for the polynomial $p$ above, we have $p(T) = c_nT^n + c_{n-1}T^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1T + c_0t^0,$ so that

$$p(T)x = c_nT^nx + c_{n-1}T^{n-1}x + \ldots + c_1Tx + c_0T^0,$$ where $T^0$ is the identity matrix.

I'll assume that if you've got the notation down, you can take it from there.